# Error: package or namespace load failed for "dplyr", "rlang" 0.4.11 is already loaded, but gt 1.0.2 is required

Tags: r

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required

I wrote library(dplyr), I want to execute mutate() function for that I try to load dplyr, for which I am getting error like this.

Comment: You may need to update your R installation - what version of R are you using?

Comment: You need to update `rlang`.  `install.packages("rlang")`.

Comment: you might need to restart R (in RStudio under the Session menu, or call `.rs.restartR()`), then update rlang as suggested above, then `library(dplyr)` will most likely work ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.